# unit testing by phpunit for zend framework 2 application

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, doctrine, phpunit

I am working on unit test in phpunit. I am trying to mocking an entity repository function **getTips().** this function is called in controller.

My test code for mocking the **getTips** function is below:

```
 $settingsObj = $this->createMock(\Base\Entity\Setting::class);

        $settingsObj->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getTips')
            ->will($this->returnValue([]));

        $settingsRepository = $this->getMockBuilder(\Base\Repository\Setting::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
        $settingsRepository->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getTips')
            ->will($this->returnValue($settingsObj));

$entityManager = $this->getMockBuilder(EntityManager::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
        $entityManager->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getRepository')
            ->will($this->returnValue($settingsRepository));
```

I am getting this error:

> Trying to configure method "getTips" which cannot be configured
>   because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is
>   static

Comment: Check if method `getTips()` exists in `\Base\Entity\Setting` _and_ in `\Base\Repository\Setting`. It must be missing in at least one of these two.

Comment: In case you are using magic getters, you need to mock `__call` instead

Comment: Entity was created for doctrine. and repository class is added in entity. for ex: * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Base\Repository\Setting") .                               and getTips() only exists in \Base\Repository\Setting.

Comment: @Gordon, I am not using magic getters